# Php gunzip and get name

Tags: php

Good morning!

I unzipped the archive using php, but after that I need to get the name of the files and perform another action, but I can not figure out how to do it.

Is it possible to do this with php? If so, tell me how and, if possible, an example, even a light one.

Thanks

```
$filelist = glob("/emp/*.gz");

$filedirtxt = glob("/emp/*.txt");


foreach ($filelist as $key => $value) {
    
    $filename = pathinfo($value);

    $gzname = $filename['basename'];

    $gunzip = shell_exec("gunzip "."/emp/".$gzname);

foreach ($filedirtxt as $keytxt => $valuetxt) {
        
        $filename_txt = pathinfo($valuetxt);

        $name_txt = $filename_txt['basename'];

        echo $name_txt."\n";

    }
    
}
```

Comment: There is an example using [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

Comment: You should try calling `$filedirtxt = glob("/emp/*.txt");` *after* you unzip the files (so during the loops), not before. The files don't exist yet if you try to glob them before.